# Draw area/polygon with a hole in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, draw

How can I draw an area/polygon with a hole using fillPoly() in OpenCV?

[image: Like this]

The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaf30888828337aa4c6b56782b5dfbd4b7) says that it is possible, but I cannot figure out how to.

Comment: Note that this obviously is not a filled polygon (even with a hole). That's a drawn (not filled) polyline. With really fat lines (so big `thickness` parameter)

Comment: You can draw a large black polygon and then a smaller white one centered at the same location over the black one. Both would be drawn with cv2.fillPoly().

Answer (score 3):

To reproduce a similar image, as I said in comment, you don't want to fill a polygon. You want to draw a polylines, with fat lines. Like this

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=np.full((250,500,3), 255, dtype=np.uint8) # A white 500x250 rgb image
lines=np.array([[50,100], [200,50], [300,70], [450,150], [220,210], [120,200]], dtype=np.int32) # Array of points of the polylines
# Draw the polylines (closed, hence `True`), in black (`(0,0,0)`), with fat lines (`thickness=80`)
# Note that 2nd argument is [lines] not lines. It need to be an array of 1 array of points (themselves being array of 2 components)
cv2.polylines(img, [lines], True, color=(0,0,0), thickness=80) 
cv2.imshow('result', img) # Just to display the result
cv2.waitKey(0) # close display when you hit a key
```

Result is
[image]
(Drawn with matplotlib, not cv2, just to have the scale)

If you really want to use polyfill ability to draw polygon with holes, that is done by giving more that one polyline in the array in 2nd argument of polyfill (there is a reason why we needed to pass `[lines]` and not `lines` in the previous code: because it could have been not just one polyline, but several ones, so it could have been `[lines1, lines2]`. This is our case this time. We need 2 polygon: one outer one, and the inner one for the hole).

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=np.full((250,500,3), 255, dtype=np.uint8)
lines=np.array([[50,100], [200,50], [300,70], [450,150], [220,210], [120,200]], dtype=np.int32)
hole=np.array([[150,100], [260,80], [260,120]], dtype=np.int32)

cv2.fillPoly(img, [lines,hole], (0,0,0))

cv2.imshow('result', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Note that the polygon is smaller, though the outer polyline is the same. That is because this times, I didn't use line thickness.

At last, if you want, to use polyfill to have a picture looking a bit like the 1st one, that is with the hole being the same as the outer polygon, but smaller, then just compute the 2nd polygon (hole) from the first one.

For example, we can choose a center at (220,130), and reduce the distance from this center by applying a factor (less than 1, to make it smaller), and add the center back.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=np.full((250,500,3), 255, dtype=np.uint8)
lines=np.array([[50,100], [200,50], [300,70], [450,150], [220,210], [120,200]], dtype=np.int32)
# Note the .astype, necessary because after the *0.5 the array became an array of floats
# and cv2 needs coordinates to be array of ints.
hole=((lines-[220,130])*0.5+[220,130]).astype(np.int32)

cv2.fillPoly(img, [lines,hole], (0,0,0))
cv2.imshow('result', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]